# How to use ssh with socks port forwarding through 2nd network card?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

From work, I ssh into my home ubuntu 14.04 LTS system through eth0, which is connected to my home router and cable modem.  With ssh port forwarding as sock proxy , I can surf from work as my home ip address.  Simple so far.

So now, I use the wireless network connection (wlan0) of my home ubuntu server  to connect to a portable cellular hotspot, and ifconfig tells me that wlan0 has an ip address of 192.168.0.46

Can I ssh into my server with the -b option to bind to the wlan card (192.168.0.46), so that I can use port forwarding to appear as a different ip address than my home IP?   If so, I guess I would need to set up the gateway of wlan0 so that the ip packets go through my hotspot, correct?   I don't know how to do that

Comment: http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html

Comment: Why not to run a second `sshd` instance that listening on different IP (ListenAddress) ?

Comment: I tried that, but was unsuccessful.  Although sshd will support multiple instances, there is no official documentation on how to do that, so it becomes a "hack" relying on unofficial instructions from somebody who did it on a different distro or version, every document I found required hacking a copy of the /etc/init.d/sshd service startup script which had an incompatibility with the upstart model, for example.

Comment: There is universal startup mechanism - cron. Drop something like `@reboot root  /usr/sbin/sshd -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config4secondInterface` to `/etc/cron.d`. You may also start the same way some `watchdog` script that check if second instance is running and if not then spawn it with `-f ` option